# My repaint() isn't doing anything and I'm at a complete loss

Tags: java, awt, overlay, vlcj

I've been working on this for some time now and I can't seem to figure out where I have gone wrong. I'm working on a VLCJ project and trying to use an overlay to display changes to the video, like volume for example, and only display it for 3 seconds from the last input. Everything seems to work great except for the fact that the repaint() doesn't change the text in the overlay at all while it is displaying.

Here is my code...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.OverlayApi;

class Overlay extends Window implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String text;
    private int x, y;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private FontMetrics metric;                                     // the metrics from the graphics
    private int stringWidth;                                        // the width of the string that is currently being displayed
    private OverlayApi overlay;
    private long startTimer;

    public Overlay(Window owner)
    {
        super(owner);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        text = "";
        x = (int) getOwner().getLocation().getX();
        y = (int) getOwner().getLocation().getY();
        running = false;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        Font fnt = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN,32);
        g2D.setFont(fnt);
        metric = g2D.getFontMetrics(fnt);                       // get the font size so it can figure out how wide the text is
        stringWidth = metric.stringWidth(text);                 // get the width of the current text field
                                                                // make a rectangle the size of the text and fill it in with black
        g2D.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, stringWidth, g2D.getFont().getSize() + 3));

        g2D.setPaint(Color.white);
        g2D.drawString(text, x, y + g2D.getFont().getSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        while (running)
        {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1)
            {
                if (timesUp())
                {
                    overlay.enable(false);
                    running = false;
System.out.println("STOPPING");
                }
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)    render();
        }
    }

    private void render()
    {
        this.repaint();
    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        startTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        overlay.enable(true);
        if (!running)
        {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
            running = true;
        }
    }

    private boolean timesUp()
    {
        long et = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long time = et - startTimer;
            long sec = 0;
        if (time > 1000)
        {
            sec = (time / 1000) % 60;
            if (sec == 3)   return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setText(String s)
    {
        this.text = s;
    }
    public String getText()
    {   return this.text;   }

    public void setOverlay(OverlayApi overlayRef)
    {   this.overlay = overlayRef;  }
}
```

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck, thank you

**--UPDATED--**

So, I completely removed the `Thread` from the equation and still no dice. I also removed the use of `AWT` and tried a `JLabel` but even that isn't updating. Its all the same problem...

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I don't know this API, so can't comment closely. What I will say is that the `Thread` you create will be independent of the gui so if it's meant to synchronize with it, you might have a problem. Looks like you're using some sort of timer, which probably ought to be a Swing `Timer` if it's gui-oriented. Closer inspection reveals you're needing an embedded VLC. You should probably be using a `JPanel`, not `Window`. What's the timing about? More broadly, what's your [goal](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/117-smart-questions)?

Comment: Why are you using java.awt , javax.swing is the standard step up now. Two points, call repaint after changing the setting text, also on the main window, on initialisation, call setIgnoreRepaint(false) , java.awt level is very difficult to kick along with repaint!

Comment: I originally tried using a Swing Timer but kept running into an issue...say you press the up arrow to increase volume by 1, wait 2 seconds and then press it again. Now what I want is to have the overlay stay on the screen for 3 seconds after the second up arrow. But with Swing Timer, I would then have 2 Timers, one ending in 1 second and the other ending in 3 seconds and when the first Timer ends, it gets rid of the overlay display even thou the second Timer still has 2 more seconds on its Timer.

Comment: Again, it's difficult to know exactly what you're doing, but can't you get the player's *own* volume controls to show?

Comment: If you wait the 3 seconds between the commands you input, the display overlay displays everything correctly, and every command is processed correctly no matter what is displayed, it just doesn't update the overlay in real time which is what I would like.

Comment: Not sure what you really need or why timers are involved. This is caused by your not describing your [goal](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/117-smart-questions)

Comment: @SamuelMarchant: unfortunately VLCJ requires that you use the java.awt.Window for the OverlayApi and I tried both of your suggestions and neither one worked sadly

Comment: @g00se: I don't need a timer but I can't do what I want to do without a timer of some kind. I'm unaware of how to do a timed task without a timer of some kind. Everything works just like its supposed to, including the timer, except for the fact that if the program is already displaying some data, that display isn't updating when I call the repaint() method

Comment: For example, if volume is at 50% and I hit the UP arrow 10 times in quick succession to raise the volume to 60%, the display only shows 51% and doesn't increment like i would like it to. The volume does in fact go up to 60%, and if i wait the 3 seconds for the display to go away and then hit the UP arrow for the 11th time, it shows 61%. So its working in the background, its just that the display isn't updating in real time

Comment: I agree  the first comment, thread will complete it's "task" then die, but there is no definite task neither control of the state of the thread (see thread.yield() in the API docs) it's an overexpensive way of doing something that appears to be either existent or not existent. Either it's running as part of the GUI or it is not! (Aside:  Should put on the main Window setIgnoreRepaint(false); anyhow.).  Although thread is there for three seconds, the thread could simply decide to idle or yield for an indefinite period, but also setting top priority may take over the GUI and stop the player.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant: I put the `setIgnoreRepaint(false)` in both the Overlay Window and the main frame as well, and i put in a display in the paint method to see if it was running it and sure enough, its running it and the value of text in the paint class is correct (as in what I want it to display) as well.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant: I even found a way to get rid of `AWT` and instead use `JLabel` and even removed the `Thread` and still the problem persists...

Comment: "Overlay" is a bit strange, you imply it overlays something else, so should not be the "top level" window. Top level window is either a Window or Frame swing or awt.

Comment: Hazard a guess, you would have your main (pardon the pun) top level window or frame and insert to it as the first added element a layered pane. The first and always bottom layer would be the viewing window, and second layer would be a lone Component class as the "overlay" painting layer for messages etc.

Comment: 'Overlay' is a term used in the API in question, and yes, their class seems to be based on lower level AWT classes, not Swing

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/overlay/OverlayTest.java) is one of the overlay examples. Unfortunately the examples do not build for me, so I have no idea what this is all about

Comment: @g00se: yeah, it works for me but it has the same problem that my current one has

Comment: @SamuelMarchant: yeah, the top layer needs to be transparent or kept to the size of the text that it is displaying.

Comment: And I have found out that my program works awesomely, if i minimize it and bring it back everytime the text in the overlay is changed

Comment: That suggests that the gui thread is being blocked

Comment: Are you using the exact same component graphics reference for repaint paint() itself is overridden for construction but you must call repaint the overlay.repaint() when and after you make a change.